# How to create jssecacerts certificate file in Java 7

Tags: java, jboss

Following link says that how to create jssecacerts for secure mail certificate for Java 7

http://infposs.blogspot.com/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html

But once I try to send mail exception gives as "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present..."

If I'm not incorrect new jssecacerts certificate file should be saved under the working directory and we have to copy it to jdk\jre\lib\security manually.

Also I would like to know that in Java 7 will it update cacerts file or existing jssecacerts file in the jdk\jre\lib\security directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present..

This exception points to SAN- Subject Alternative Name. 
This is used for host name verification- SAN will contain IP address(es) or Host Name(s) of the machine carrying the certificate.

In your case most probably email server is not accepting your certificate because of null SAN (it is strictly verifying host names/IPs).

I suggest you to create certificate with SAN- http://blogs.technet.com/b/isablog/archive/2011/10/09/how-to-generate-a-certificate-with-subject-alternative-names-san.aspx

On Linux Flavours : http://lanestechblog.blogspot.in/2009/04/creating-ssl-certificates-with-multiple.html

If given by CA(Certification Authority) - ask them to generate it with SAN for your host.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer but, My Platform is cent os server (version 5.9) and jboss-6.0.0.20100216-M2 

when I was in java 1.6.0_26 jasscerts security file created properly (according to the given url in earlier post). and working fine with cent os server version 5.5 and jboss jboss-6.0.0.20100216-M2.

After, migrated to java version 1.7.0_25, I unable to create that jasscerts security file. 
I would like to know that any other way using in Java 7 for this security certificate file.

Appriciate if anyone can help for resolve this issue

Comment: Modified by answer to include linux guide.